# JAVA _Home is not set in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, installation

I am a beginner with hadoop and  trying to install and run hadoop in my Ubuntu as a single node cluster. This is my JAVA_HOME in my hadoop_env.sh

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}
```

But when I run it the following errors come-

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

How do I remove this error?

Answer (score 19):

I debugged the code and found out that even though JAVA_HOME is set in the environment, the value is lost as ssh connections to other hosts is made inside the code, and the JAVA_HOME variable that was showing well set in start-dfs.sh became unset in hadoop-env.sh.

The solution to this problem will be to set JAVA_HOME variable in hadoop-env.sh and it should work properly.

Comment: As for @toobee, this worked for me, but why. I'm not a Linux pro, so why is JAVA_HOME not set when SSHing to the local machine? I have mine set in my ~/.profile

Comment: That was a bug in the code of Hadoop. The value of JAVA_HOME gets overriden inside the code with something else, even if you have it set in ~/.profile.

Comment: Very accurate. Just as an alternative solution you can also set it in /etc/environment and it would work!:)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error and solved it with Soil Jain's remark, but to make it even a bit more clear: the hadoop-env.sh uses an expression such as

```
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

if you hard-code the path to your JVM installation it works

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java...
```

this resolution by environmental variable as is seems to fail. Hard-coding fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I used to set a hard-code like `/usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_231` but dataNode restart fail get `resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ;  /usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/hadoop/bin/hdfs --config /usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/hadoop/conf --daemon stop datanode'' returned 1. ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_231 does not exist.`

Answer (score 6):

Under your **HADOOP_HOME/conf** directory please update the `hadoop-env.sh` file. It has entry to export JAVA_HOME.

Setting to appropriate JAVA_HOME in this file should solve your issue.

Comment: I have updated it as export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun .. still same error

Comment: On my case. Started Hadoop successfully  after removing java_home variable in user bash profile and adding entry above mentioned in haddop-env.sh file.

 one info:  In latest version of Hadoop, location of hadoop-env.sh file has been changed. i.e. HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

Answer (score 2):

Are you loading `hadoop_env.sh`? you may be refering to  `hadoop-env.sh` ( dash instead of underscore - that is under conf directory)

BTW, This is a very useful guide for quick installation :

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: I have put it in the question. I have updated the export for the JAVA_HOME. Still when I run it the error comes. Is is due to using openjdk7?and ya its hadoop-env.sh. Sorry for the typo mistake

Comment: Nope. its not set at all - if not finding the java that would be another error

Comment: The easier way will be to export JAVA_HOME via your .bashrc file

Comment: I have set it in the .bashrc file too. This is what I have put in both the hadoop-env.sh file and the .bashrc file                                     export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun

Comment: i can't suggest you more than start installing again using the guide i sended you above

Answer (score 2):

First, you must set JAVA_HOME in your `hadoop_env.sh` . (your local JAVA_HOME in .bashrc would likely to be ignore somehow)

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Then, set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` point to directory of your `hadoop_env.sh` . In ~/.bashrc, add the following line:

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR
```

Where `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop` is the directory contained `hadoop_env.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using hadoop 2.8.0. Even though I exported JAVA_HOME (I put it in .bashrc), I still caught this error while trying to run start-dfs.sh.

```
user@host:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0 $ echo $JAVA_HOME
<path_to_java>
user@host:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0 $ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
...
user@host:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0 $ sbin/start-dfs.sh
...
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

The only way I could get it to run was to add JAVA_HOME=path_to_java to etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh and then source it:

```
:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0 $ grep JAVA_HOME etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
#export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JAVA_HOME=path_to_java
user@host:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0 $ source etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

Maybe that (sourcing hadoop-env.sh) was implied in the posts above. Just thought someone should say it out loud. Now it runs. I've encountered other issues (due, I suspect, to the limited resources on the server I'm using), but at least I got past this one.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers should work as long as you are using default conf directory `$HADOOP_HOME/conf` or `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`. Here are a few things you should do if you're using a different conf folder.

1. Copy the `hadoop-env.sh` file from the default conf directory to your conf folder, say `/home/abc/hadoopConf`.
2. Replace the line

   ```
   #export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
   ```

   with the following:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
   export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/abc/hadoopConf
   ```

Change the values appropriately. If you have any other environment variables related to hadoop configured in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` or `.bash_profile` consider adding them next to the above lines.

Answer (score -1):

It not know space between Program and Files: "Program Files". 
So, I copy folder of jdk to C: or folder which not contains space in name of folder and assign: export JAVA_HOME=Name_Path_Copied. I see it run ok